# Declarative pipeline send email

Tags: email, jenkins

i need to send a mail notification using jenkins (if it is a success build or someting went wrong)

Right now i have something like that:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

...Some stages ...

post {
        success {
            mail to:"someone@hotmail.com", subject:"SUCCESS: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", body: "Yay, we passed."
        }
        failure {
            mail to:"someone@hotmail.com", subject:"FAILURE: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", body: "Boo, we failed."
        }
    }   
}
```

But when i execute i get the following error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Caused: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I guess i cannot send on the port 25 i need to send it on the port 465.. am i wrong?But i dont know how can i do this.

In most of the examples they use plugins to the jenkins, but i can **only use** code (**declarative pipeline**)

suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins default email server attempts to run through your localhost on port 25. That error message indicates, as you have guessed, that you need to change the email settings.

To do so, go to **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System** -> **Email Notifcation** or **Extended Email Notification**

As an aside, unless you have an email server running locally (and I'd be surprised if that was the case), changing the local port number won't work. You would need to point it to an external server. [Here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GMail) is a setting page for having Jenkins use the Google SMTP server, for instance

Answer (score 0):

You may have to let the Jenkins *master* send the email (most agents/nodes probably don't have a mail server):

```
success {
    node("master") { 
        mail ...
    }
}
```